# How to include multiple related objects with Parse

Tags: rest, api, parse-platform

To begin, **happy new year** everyone =)

I currently have a problem with **Parse framework** *Rest API*. 
Indeed, I created an "**Agriculteurs**" object containing some "**Produits**" objects in an array like this :

```
{
  "name": "MyName",
  "surname": "Surname",
  "produits": {
    "__op": "AddRelation",
    "objects": [
      {
        "__type": "Pointer",
        "className": "Produits",
        "objectId": "iaMxwp9RcQ"
      },
      {
        "__type": "Pointer",
        "className": "Produits",
        "objectId": "J7EPowIF1w"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

So I want to retrieve the list of all "**Agriculteurs**" with the list of all "**Produits**" included. Of course, I tried by adding the keyword : *?include=produits* but it's not working...

```
http://MY_URL:28000/parse/classes/Agriculteurs?include=produits
```

Here is what I get (I want to get all the products not the *raw relation*) :

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "objectId": "6MypK8IQqT",
      "name": "MyName",
      "surname": "Surname",
      "produits": {
        "__type": "Relation",
        "className": "Produits"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem by using the "**AddUnique**" keyword.

```
"produits": {
    "__op": "AddUnique",
    "objects": [
      {
        "__type": "Pointer",
        "className": "Produits",
        "objectId": "iaMxwp9RcQ"
      },
      {
        "__type": "Pointer",
        "className": "Produits",
        "objectId": "J7EPowIF1w"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Using *?include=produits* works fine now :) !